# I am not able to parse string as it needs double quotes format

Tags: apex, webservices, json

Please find the code.

```
Apikey= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Apikey');
jsonstring='{FirstName:"}'+Apikey;

public void parseJsonString(){
   JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonstring);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) { 
     if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {       
       while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
          if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
            Jsonparsercls le = (Jsonparsercls)parser.readValueAs(Jsonparsercls.class);
            Lead leadobj=new Lead();
            leadobj.FirstName=le.FirstName;
            leadobj.LastName=le.LastName;
            leadobj.Company=le.Company;
            leadobj.City=le.City;
            leadobj.State=le.State;
            leadobj.PostalCode=le.PostalCode;
            leadobj.Phone=le.Phone;
            leadobj.Status=le.Status;
            lstlead.add(leadobj);
          }
```

An example of the JSON string would be as follows:

```
jsonstring='[
             {
              "FirstName":"Balaji",
              "LastName":"Malemarpuram",
              "Company":"Oracle"
             },
             ...
            ]
```

Comment: Could use a bit more detail. What is the string you're trying to parse? What is the error?

Comment: public String jsonstring{get;set;}

Comment: I want dynamic variable in the string jsonstring='[{"FirstName":"Balaji","LastName":"Malemarpuram","Company":"Oracle"}]

Comment: You can also edit and update your own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON String is not in the correct format:

```
jsonstring='{FirstName:"}'+Apikey;
```

should be

```
jsonstring='{"FirstName" : "'+Apikey+'"}';
```

Once you get your string you can manually check it here to ensure it is a valid JSON string: http://jsonlint.com

**sfdcfox (Great Suggestion)**

> jsonString = JSON.serialize(new Map{ 'FirstName' =>
>   ApiKey });

Comment: I personally use JSON.serialize for purposes like this: `jsonString = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, String>{ 'FirstName' => ApiKey });` This also avoids needing to properly escape characters, for example, if ApiKey has a quote in it...